# Depth of sea and point at which waves break

Tags: waves

Following up on this answer, is the point at which waves break on the sea shore a guide to the depth of the sea at that point? Could it indicate eg hidden rocks?

[Explain the direction of waves on sea shore](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13841/explain-the-direction-of-waves-on-sea-shore/13844#13844)

Comment: yes it does. Wikipedia quotes the critical number for the ratio of wave height to wavelength to be .17: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_waves#Wave_breaking

Comment: @luksen, this was an interesting article. Also states that the waves break when the depth is down to just 25% more than the wave height .